# ¿Cuál es la manera mas eficiente de clonar objetos en Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Estoy necesitando clonar un objeto en JavaScript, de momento para objetos simples que únicamente contengan solo atributos lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera usando `JSON.stringify()` y `JSON.parse()`:

```
let original = { nombre: 'juan', apellido: 'peres', edad: 23 }
let copia = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(original));
```

No creo que sea lo mas optimo (por eso la pregunta) pero funciona, la dudad es, como hacer para clonar cualquier objeto que contenga métodos o funciones internas definidas por ejemplo.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript/5344074#5344074

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Aqui](https://jherax.wordpress.com/2014/07/20/js-clonando-objetos/) un articulo muy bueno sobre la clonacion:

```js
/** Clona un objeto (deep-copy)
 * @param  {Any}    from: el objeto a clonar
 * @param  {Object} dest: (opcional) objeto a extender
 * @return {Any} retorna el nuevo objeto clonado
 */
var fnClone = (function() {
  // @Private
  var _toString = Object.prototype.toString;
 
  // @Private
  function _clone (from, dest, objectsCache) {
    var prop;
    // determina si @from es un valor primitivo o una funcion
    if (from === null || typeof from !== "object") return from;
    // revisa si @from es un objeto ya guardado en cache
    if (_toString.call(from) === "[object Object]") {
      if (objectsCache.filter(function (item) {
        return item === from;
      }).length) return from;
      // guarda la referencia de los objetos creados
      objectsCache.push(from);
    }
    // determina si @from es una instancia de alguno de los siguientes constructores
    if (from.constructor === Date || from.constructor === RegExp || from.constructor === Function ||
      from.constructor === String || from.constructor === Number || from.constructor === Boolean) {
      return new from.constructor(from);
    }
    if (from.constructor !== Object && from.constructor !== Array) return from;
    // crea un nuevo objeto y recursivamente itera sus propiedades
    dest = dest || new from.constructor();
    for (prop in from) {
      // TODO: allow overwrite existing properties
      dest[prop] = (typeof dest[prop] === "undefined" ?
          _clone(from[prop], null, objectsCache) :
          dest[prop]);
    }
    return dest;
  }
 
  // función retornada en el closure
  return function (from, dest) {
    var objectsCache = [];
    return _clone(from, dest, objectsCache);
  };
 
}());

var freeman, david;
 
function Freeman() {
    this.name = "Gordon Freeman";
    this.character = "Freeman";
    this.game = "Half-Life";
    this.friends = [];
}
 
david = {
    name: "David Rivera",
    character: "jherax",
    friends: [],
    languages: new RegExp(/javascript|jquery|c#|sql|java|vb/i),
    greeting: function() { return "Hi, I am " + this.name },
    info: {
        job: "programmer",
        birth: new Date()
    }
};
 
freeman = new Freeman();
 
//creamos la referencia circular
freeman.friends = [david, "Barney Calhoun"];
david.friends = [freeman, "John Carmack"];
 
//clonamos el objeto @david
var cloned = fnClone(david);
 
//modificamos propiedades del objeto original
david.name = david.name + " (jherax)";
david.friends.push("Jim Rynor");
 
//vemos que @cloned no fue modificado
console.log("original:", david.name, david.friends);
console.log("clonado:", cloned.name, cloned.friends);
```

Comment: Ya puse el link del autor @AlvaroMontoro pense que lo habia puesto. Lo siento

Comment: no pasa nada. Me llamó la atención por cómo estaba escrito

Answer (score 5):

Puedes utilizar [Object.assign(objetivo, ...fuentes)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/assign), pero es a partir de **ECMAScript 2015**.

```
const objeto = { id: 1, name: 'abc' };
const objetoClonado = Object.assign({}, objeto);
```

Answer (score 0):

Con jQuery podés utilizar la función extend.

var copia = jQuery.extend(true, {}, original);

Acá te dejo el link para que averigues mejor.
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/

Comment: no creo que esa sea una buena manera ya que extend mezcla o combina el contenido de los objetos

Comment: Justamente lo que hace es pasar todas las propiedades del objeto original a un JSON vacío, uno por uno y guardas el resultado en la variable copia. El primer objeto q se pasa es modificado, los demás no son alterados, solo se copia sus valores. JQuery mismo lo usa para dicho fin internamente.

Answer (score 0):

Hay una forma muy sencilla de clonar un objeto con el método estático assign de Object

```html
var obj = { a: 1 };
var copy = Object.assign({}, obj);
console.log(copy); // { a: 1 }
```

[enlace documentación de js mozilla developer network](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)